# Can't create online meeting using Microsoft Graph Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-calendar

When I'm trying to create an online meeting I get this error:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jhIY.png)

I have all needed permissions:
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF522.png)

The same problem occurs when I try using the calendar endpoint and pass params to create an online meeting inside:
[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zoa9W.png)

As u can see the event is created but without an online meeting.
allowedOnlineMeetingProviders is equal to "teamsForBuissness":
[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpQHY.png)

I want to mention that it was working fine like 1-1,5 months ago.
What can be the cause of this problem?

I'm expect to create a online meeting and join url teams link.